# Missing profile features

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page

In general, the C.SE profile page is nice looking than the default one (IMO).  However, I've noticed it lacks a couple nice features of the default page.  Most notably, the badge tracking gadget.  While most of the badges can, no doubt, be tracked in other ways, it is neat to have a quick glance to see where I stand on a variety of badges.  The other feature I've noticed that is missing is the impact score.

On meta.SE, I figured out both of these things are relatively new features, so they were presumably added after the C.SE profile page was designed.

Is there another way to access these two features?  If not, could they possibly be added to the profile layout?

Comment: I hate change and new things, so no.

Comment: Related new post: [A design update is coming!](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/5789/21576)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a function of Stack Exchange rolling out rewrites of the CSS architecture for all their sites and [Christianity.SE not having gotten the rewrite yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253359/145951). The new profile features will come when they get around to updating the way the template works.